# QGraphicsView and the decorator pattern

Tags: c++, qt, oop, design-patterns

The question applies to the class `QGraphicsView` of the qt library.
However, the problem is more general. So, if I am not missing any special mechanism in qt, it can probably be discussed without knowing qt.

I am subclassing `QGraphicsView` to add some features that I need.
E.g. I have a `ScalableView`, `PannableView` and `LabeledView` to add independent functionality.

The sublassing I use for now is linear in the following sense:
`ScalableView` is derived from `QGraphics` view.
`PannableView` is derived from `ScalableView` view.
`LabeledView` is derived from `PannableView` view.

Since those features are independent, there is a design flaw.
Applying the **decorator pattern** to come around this seems appropriate for me.
The problem there is, `QGraphicsView` is not an interface and there exists no interface class like *QAbstractGraphicsView*. So, for me it is not clear how that pattern could be implemented.

A different idea would be to use templates. So I could derive each of the views from a template `T`. Then, I could make insantiations like `ScalableView<PannableView<LabeledView>>>`.

Do you see any better solution to that? I would prefer a way to implement the decorator pattern in this situation, since I would like to avoid to many template classes that would increase compilation time.

Comment: What does a ScalableView and PannableView add to a QGraphicsView, which isn't already available by the class itself? If you're just removing functionality, then what's the reason for this?

Comment: It is not removing, it is adding functionality. It makes the view scalable using the mouse wheel and offers a function to fit the view. PannableView offers left click panning using the mouse.

Comment: Why not just inherit once from QGraphicsView, do you need different views with different functionality?

Comment: Yes, this is the main reason.

Comment: I don't see why you can't use the decorator pattern. As far as I know you don't need an interface for it, just a pointer or reference to QGraphicsView.

Comment: Template solution won't work in this case as QObject derived classes cannot be templated.

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy They can be, as long as they don't have their own signals or slots. The signals and slots can still be provided by a shim, non-templated class.

Comment: @DrD The problem I see there is the following. To apply the decorator pattern I would introduce a class DecoratorView. This would be derived from QGraphicsView and must aggregate a QGraphicsView. This is possible with an interface. But with a non-abstract class I end up with two different instances of QGraphicsView.

Comment: Oh, I see. And I guess building your own interface of QGraphicsView is out of the question, due to the workload involved, otherwise you could decorate your interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution in Qt style would be to create a class that derives from `QGraphicsView` and simply has flags that control its behavior (whether it's scalable, pannable, labeled, etc.). The implementations of those behaviors would still be split into methods, so it's 
not as monolithic as it seems.

The decorator pattern can be of course easily implemented by defining an intermediate (shim) interface. The `QGraphicsView` does not need to implement that interface - the interface is only for the decorators to use.

The problem with deep inheritance is that it's impossible to finely control the interaction of the behaviors. The only control you have is the order of event processing. This may happen to be sufficient, but it has me somewhat worried. The decorator pattern implemented without embellishment shares this issue.

Comment: Thanks, this would be a way to go. However as you mentioned, the drawback is the monolithic nature of this approach. In my eyes, the functionality I would like to add is too complex for single methods.

Comment: @SebastianK I didn't say to split it into single methods, just split it into methods in general. You'll then notice how they can be exposed via a common shim interface, and that leads directly to the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the full design, this may or may not work, but perhaps this will help.

One possible method would be to encapsulate the QGraphicsView and create delegate objects that provide the different functionality that you require. The delegates would then be responsible for providing the interface to the graphics view and forwarding messages.

This would mean creating a different delegate for the different types of functionality; a ScalableDelegate, a PannableDelegate and a LabeledDelegate.

As the delegates are separate objects and not inherited from the QGraphicsView, you can gain a lot of functionality from installing event filters on the graphics views.

Then, instead of objects interacting with your GraphicsView, they communicate via the relevant delegate.

If this is too restrictive,you may need to inherit from QGraphicsView to create a view with the functionality you need and then use the delegates to expose the required functionality as desired.